# fromState in angular ui-router returns empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When using angular ui-router, the `fromState` parameter returns an empty object while the `toState` works just fine, i would like to access `fromState.name`. My ctrl looks like this:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($rootScope) {

  // State change start
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, fromState){

    console.log(fromState); // -> Object {url: "/program", templateUrl: "views/program.html", resolve: Object, name: "program"}
    console.log(toState); // -> Object {} when clicking on e.g. 'news'

  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing some arguments in your stateChangeStart function.  The toParams and fromParams specifically. Check the docs for that callback again. What you have named fromState is probably really toParams, and if the state has no params, thats why it is empty.

Comment: I was just typing the same answer :) For reference, the correct function signature to use is: `$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {`